# Share files in dual boot ? Both os on different ssd with an hdd for file

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs, file-sharing

I am just going to create a dual boot pc. I have a windows 10 installed on ssd and have another hdd which store other data. I am going to add additional ssd for ubuntu 20.4.

How do I share the data between thses dual boot system? I want both os to share my files and photos through my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Format the HDD as NTFS.
- You should have no trouble with Windows. Your HDD will automatically appear in "*File Explorer*".
- For Ubuntu,

  1. Format and partition your HDD using GParted (install with `sudo apt install gparted` in terminal).
  2. Go to the "Disk" utility.
  3. Select your HDD.
  4. Select the icon with 2 cogwheels.
  5. Select "*Edit Mount Options*".
  6. Turn the "*User Session Defaults*" option to "*Off*".
  7. Check the box "*Mount at system startup*" Make sure "*Show in the user interface*" is also checked.
  8. Replace the line that says `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show` to `users,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,x-gvfs-show,utf8`
  9. Change the "*Mount point*" to something less complicated like `/mnt/MyFiles`.
  10. Change the "Filesystem Type" to `ntfs-3g`.
  11. Click "*OK*".
  12. You will see Windows system files in Ubuntu (Like `$Recycke.bin` folder. Don't delete or change things you didn't make. You will also be able to see Ubuntu files from Windows (Like `.trash`) Don't delete/change them either.

Comment: I also like to link folders from my /mnt/data partition into my /home, so my standard Pictures folder is really my folder in /mnt/data/.  If using NTFS make sure Windows fast start up is off, or Linux NTFS will not mount read/write. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred Uh is this your own comment or an OP's answer converted to a comment? Yes the fast startup thing is true though you can keep it on and still have read/write if you restart through windows to get into Ubuntu instead of shutting down. (Fast startup doesn't affect restart). As for pictures folder in /home, you can make a shortcut (symlink) of your pictures folder in `/mnt/data` and replace the Pictures folder in `/home` with it. (I have my own document folder set up like this)

Comment: @oldfred Ah sorry. reading your linked posts, I understood that you have explained how to answer those questions in those links. Thanks for putting them there.